# count letters/numbers in textarea and show it (without jQuery!)

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

I'm working with `Bootstrap` and the `CKEditor5 Classic`.

I want to have a counter with `ONKEYUP` in my `textarea` which should be shown each time the key goes up in `div id countThis`..

I only need pure javascript I've tried following but it doesnt work..

How can I make it work? thank you!

(I need it without jQuery!)

**CODE**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="form-group col-10">
    <label class="form-label" for="txt">Ddscription</label>

    <textarea id="txt" class="form-control" onkeyup="CheckInput()"></textarea>

  </div>
  <div class="col-2 mt-4" id="countThis"></div>
</div>
```

```
ClassicEditor
  .create(document.querySelector('#txt'))
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
  });

function CheckInput() {
  var value = document.getElementById("txt").value.length;
  console.log(value); // HERE COMES NOTHING
  document.getElementById("countThis").innerHTML = value;
}
```

Comment: This code is working fine. make sure the id `txt` is unique for the page...

Comment: No it's not.. the Editor is blocking all of my java scirpt ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to capture the event using CKEditor API instead of the keyup attribute, in this way:

```js
ClassicEditor
    .create(document.querySelector('#txt'))
    .then(editor => {
        /// Register change listener
        editor.model.document.on( 'change:data', () => {  /// <--- Changes listener

            /* ALL THE LOGIC IS DOWN HERE */

            document.getElementById("countThis").innerHTML = 
                editor    /// <--- Editor reference
                    .getData()    /// <--- Editor content
                    .replace(/<[^>]*>/g, '')    /// <--- Convert HTML to plain text
                    .replace('&nbsp;', ' ')    /// <--- Remove &nbsp; for spaces
                    .length;    /// <--- Get plain text length
        });
    })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/30.0.0/classic/ckeditor.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="form-group col-10">
    <label class="form-label" for="txt">Ddscription</label>

    <textarea id="txt" class="form-control"></textarea>

  </div>
  <div class="col-2 mt-4" id="countThis"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks works fine. is it possible that when I press "space bar" that it will not count 6 up and than down again, so when I press space bar it should add 1 ? Thank You

Comment: That's because FCK adds `&nbsp;` if there is a space at the end, you may add `.replace('&nbsp;', ' ')` after the other replace, just before `.length`. I'll modify the answer.

Comment: it's working!! THANK YOU!!